# How to return a string that has a variable inside in a shortcode?

Tags: php, shortcode

```
$output = '<p class="one"><small>'.$newsletter_one. '</small></p>'
```

Generally, when we write short codes we publish HTML like the above one, and instead of echo use return function.

How should we write this one →

```
<span class="class2" id="class3-<?php echo $random;?>"> </span>
```

Like this →

```
$output = '<span class="class2" id="class3-.$random."> </span>'
```

or does this has some flaws?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you want to return a data combined with a string, you can use one of the following methods:

Either open and close the string using `'`:

```
return '<span class="class2" id="class3-' . $random . '"> </span>';
```

Or use the double quote:

```
return "<span class='class2' id='class3-{$random}'> </span>";
```

You can simply use `$random` without the `{}` curly brackets, but it's easier to read if you use `{}`.

You can even use double quotes for the inner string, but you need to escape them:

```
return "<span class=\"class2\" id=\"class3-{$random}\"> </span>";
```

As pointed out in comments by @birgire, to make it more WordPressy, we can also escape the variable:

```
return sprintf( '<span class="class2" id="class3-%s"></span>', esc_attr( $random ) );
```

Comment: Ok. so this  `{$random}  =  . $random .`

Comment: Yes, but only if you wrap your string in double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: ps: then there's this way: :`return sprintf( '<span class="class2" id="class3-%s"></span>', esc_attr( $random.) );`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Jack Johansson's answer (I'd add a comment to that but it seems I need to have been here longer to do that than to post my own answer!) I don't think you even need the internal double quotes. AFAICT (I'm a relatively recent PHP programmer), you could just write

```
return "<span class='class2' id='class3-{$random}'> </span>";
```

and that would work just as well.