# How to return a string that has a jQuery and Ajax inside in a shortcode?

Tags: php, functions, shortcode, query-string

This is the whole code actually →

```
<script>
            jQuery.noConflict();
            jQuery(document).ready(function()
                {

                    jQuery('#mailchimp_submit-<?php echo $random?>').click(function()
                    {
                        jQuery('#process-<?php echo $random?>').css('display','block');
                        var datastring = '&name=' + escape(jQuery('#name-<?php echo $random?>').val()) + '&email=' + escape(jQuery('#email-<?php echo $random?>').val()) + '&api_key=<?php echo $mailchimp_api_key;?>&list_id=<?php echo $mailchimp_list_id;?>';
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url: '<?php echo rest_url('/chimp/rest/process_chimp/');?>',
                            data: datastring,
                            success: function(msg)
                            {
                                jQuery('#process-<?php echo $random?>').css('display','none');
                                jQuery('#newsletter_msg-<?php echo $random?>').html(msg);
                            },
                            error: function(msg)
                            {
                                jQuery('#process-<?php echo $random?>').css('display','none');
                                jQuery('#newsletter_msg-<?php echo $random?>').html(msg);
                            }
                        });
                        return false;
                    });
            });
        </script>
```

There are a lot of confusions:

## 1 →

How to handle this as this has a semicolon →

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

should I do it like this:

`$output =  'jQuery.noConflict();';` or

`$output =  'jQuery.noConflict()';` or

`$output =  'jQuery.noConflict();`'

## 2 →

How to handle one that has a function →

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
```

Like this →

```
$output =  'jQuery(document).ready(function()';
```

How to handle this →

## 4 →

```
jQuery.ajax({
              url: '<?php echo rest_url('/chimp/rest/process_chimp/');?>',
              data: datastring,
              success: function(msg)
              {
```

## 5 →

```
return false;
```

The above also needs to be modified?

Please guide me where I am going wrong, and where my approach and understanding is not correct.
[This is an Extension of this old question.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/279736/how-to-return-a-string-that-has-a-variable-inside-in-a-shortcode)

All the above code is a part of the widget that I am trying to convert into a shortcode.

Comment: Can some one help me in this o if there is some better way?

Comment: I've added an answer, but again, this has nothing to do with WordPress. Most of your questions lately have been about basic PHP and JavaScript syntax. I strongly suggest you get the fundamentals of PHP and JavaScript down before you get too complex in WordPress, and if you need help with that [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is the right place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For large amounts of HTML you're better off using output buffering with `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()`. The documentation for it is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), but the short version is that it lets you capture output to return later. That way you can just output HTML like you would in a template, but capture it and return it at the end:

```
function wpse_279827_shortcode() {
    // Do PHP stuff.
    $message = 'Hello world!';
    // Start capturing output.
    ob_start(); 
    // Close PHP tags and start outputting HTML.
    ?>

    <div>
        <h1>HTML can go here</h1>
        <p>And also php code:</p>
        <p><?php echo 'Hello!'; ?></p>
    </div>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            alert('Message variable from PHP: <?php echo $message; ?>');
        });
    </script>

    <?php
    // Reopen PHP tags and return captured output.
    return ob_get_clean(); 
}
add_shortcode( 'wpse_279827_shortcode', 'wpse_279827_shortcode' );
```